# Android Studio Proguard Debugging Obfuscated library project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mapping, proguard

I have two projects. One of them is a library project which gets output as a jar file when built, and the second project has a simple interface that uses aspects of the that output jar file.

I use proguard on the library project, using a task similar to this:

```
task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask, dependsOn: fatJar) {
    configuration 'ProguardSettings'
    printmapping file("mapping.txt")
}
```

The output jar file is shrunken and obfuscated nicely. I also have an output mapping.txt file that looks good.

My other project that contains the jar file from the library project.  Android Studio gives me the option to decompile the jar file so I can do some debugging if an issue arises. I have an option "Choose Sources...", which let's me select my project and select all the source files with the "Choose Roots" option.

However it opens up the shrunken obfuscated file which is quite hard to debug.

ie: Source

```
public static void testMethod(){
  MyClass.doSomething();
}
```

Output after selecting the source for the jar file:

```
public static void av(){
  a.v();
}
```

If I don't obfuscate the file, selecting the sources links like you would expect and is quite readable. Since I have the "mapping.txt" file, is there any way to apply that information to make debugging my library project link to the actual source?

Thanks!